# How to sample from a distribution with log likelihood a quadratic form

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, quadratic-form

In the context of the article [BiRank: Towards Ranking on Bipartite Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04396.pdf) specially the Bayesian interpretation section 5.2. I want to make inference on the vector non-negative vector $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^{n_u}$. Thus, I want to sample from a distribution with the following log-likelihood:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{u})=-(1+\eta)\sum_{i=1}^{N_u}u_i^{2}+2\sum_{i=1}^{N_u}u_i\left(\theta\sum_{j=1}^{N_p} w_{ij}\sqrt{\frac{d_j^p}{d_i^u}}+\eta u_{i}^{0}\right)-\theta^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{N_p}(d_j^{p})^{2}-\eta\sum_{i=1}^{N_u}(u_i^{0})^{2}
$$

where $w_{ij}\geq 0$, $d_i^{u}= \sum_{j}w_{ij}$, $d_j^{p}= \sum_{i}w_{ij}$, $\theta,\eta>0$ ara hyperparameters, and $\mathbf{u}^{0}$ is a fixed vector with positive values. The MAP is given by:

$$\hat{u_i}=\frac{\theta \sum_{j=1}^{N_p} w_{ij}\sqrt{\frac{d_j^{p}}{d_i^{u}}}+\eta u_{i}^{0}}{1+\eta}$$

The distribution with the above log likelihood can't be normal due to the non-negativity of $\mathbf{u}$. Furthermore, after doing some simulation using Metropolis Hastings for each individual $u_i$ the variance changes significatly for every $i\neq j$(at least from a simulated perspective).

Any idea on what should I do? Gibbs sampling?

Comment: How are $u_i$ and $u_i^0$ related??

Comment: In my particular case $u_i^{0}=\theta d_i$.

Comment: This is a truncated normal, no?

Comment: It might, I'm not 100% sure due to the fact that that the loglikelihood is from, I might be wrong, a normal distribution.

Comment: @Girigio there is only one distribution which has its log-likelihood given by a quadratic form, and that is the normal distribution :) Restricting its support leads to a truncated normal.

Comment: @John Madden Is the variance of a univariate normal distribution only related to the coefficient of the quadratic term? I almost 100% sure it is, not been able to validate with another colleague.

Comment: @Girigio Yes, the coefficient of the quadratic term is $\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}$.